# How to use text expanders like Phrasse Express inside Kitty?

Tags: kitty, textexpander

How to use text expanders inside Kitty? SSH with Kitty to Ubuntu server and want to expand some shortcuts  from Phrasse Express in Kitty's window but get only `^M` when expand with `TAB` key.
Text expanding works in Conemu, but not in Kitty, Putty, Mobaxterm, Mintty.

Comment: I found solution for this and now I can expand anything...Default option for inserting text in PhrasseExpress is via Windows clipboard, change that option in Settings to Paste via keystroke simulation (2nd option)